# Find the list of file changes since last commit using mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am working on a project and I have to find the number of files added, deleted and modified since the last `commit` in `mercurial` hg.

`hg status` gives us the list of files which are modified, deleted and unknown. So using `hg status` is there any way i can get a count of all files added, deleted and modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each file added, modified or deleted is listed on a line by itself, so you can count the lines for each. For instance, on Unix-like systems with the `wc` command:

```
hg status --modified | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the **last commit** it's always 0.

Describe your business-task in business-words